# How can I convert XML to HTML?

Tags: html, xml, tags, confluence-rest-api

I try to get a HTML page from Atlassian Confluence API but it returns a context like this. How can I convert these to standard HTML tags?

```
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(153,153,153);"><br /></span></p>
    <h2><ac:image><ri:attachment ri:filename="welcome.png" /></ac:image><br />&nbsp; <span style="color: rgb(128,128,128);">With Confluence it is easy to create, edit and share content with your team. Choose a topic below to start learning how.</span></h2>
    <h2><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><br /></span></h2>
    <ol>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="What is Confluence? (step 1 of 9)" /><ac:link-body>What is Confluence?<br /><br /></ac:link-body></ac:link></span></li>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="A quick look at the editor (step 2 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[A quick look at the editor]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link><br />&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Let's edit this page (step 3 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Let's edit this page]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link><br /><br /></span></li>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Prettify the page with an image (step 4 of 9)" /><ac:link-body>Prettify the page with an image<br /><br /></ac:link-body></ac:link></span></li>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Get serious with a table (step 5 of 9)" /><ac:link-body>Get serious with a table<br /></ac:link-body></ac:link></span><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);">&nbsp;</span></li>
        <li><span style="color: rgb(0,0,128);"><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Lay out your page (step 6 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Lay out your page]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link>&nbsp;<br /><br /></span></li>
        <li><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Learn the wonders of autoconvert (step 7 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Learn the wonders of autoconvert]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link>&nbsp;<br /><br /></li>
        <li><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Tell people what you think in a comment (step 8 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Tell people what you think in a comment]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link>&nbsp;<br /><br /></li>
        <li><ac:link><ri:page ri:content-title="Share your page with a team member (step 9 of 9)" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Share your page with a team member]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link><br /><br /></li>
        <li><a href="http://directory.apache.org">Apache Directory</a></li>
    </ol>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(128,128,128);"><br /></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(128,128,128);"><br /></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(128,128,128);"><br /></span></p><p style="text-align: right;">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: `p` , `h2` , `ol` - are already "standart html tags" ; all others are simply ignored by browsers

Comment: I know p , h2 , ol are html tags. But stylesheet is not work with these tags.

Comment: what do you mean? working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/KM6y8/

Comment: Not sure why you're being down-voted... it's a valid question to ask how to convert content from Confluence's internal storage format to plain HTML. Maybe you didn't frame the question in a way that someone un-familiar with Confluence would understand?

Answer (score 2):

`<ac:image> <ri:attachment../>` etc. are confluence xhtml macros and will be rendered by confluence itself on page output. you have to call a render method of the confluence api to get that to transformed html.

Confluence offers you a function for that in the confluence [remote SOAP API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+Confluence+Methods#RemoteConfluenceMethods-Pages) -> Page -> Management:

```
String renderContent(String token, String spaceKey, String pageId, String content)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for exporting Confluence pages to HTML. It is called Scroll HTML Exporter.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-html/server/overview